# Ruby on Rails: how to assign a random number to users without storing it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I assign a table of users a random number between 1 and 9 without needing to store it in the db (to recall it later).

Is there some way to hash their user_id into returning a number between a range (and then get the same number for that user every time that function would be called).

Comment: Why not just store it in the database? That's what the database is for, data persistence. Unless you can present a compelling reason *not* to put this in the database, the correct answer really is just to store it there like you would any other piece of data.

Comment: @meagar: one of the compelling reasons can be that he simply wants to group the users using numbers, but randomly. He may not want to store this number in the database, and simply wants an algorithm that can replicate its results, every time. Infact, this seems to be an interesting question :)

Comment: @Stoic I first read his question as specifically stating that he needs to be able to retrieve the same number for the same record at any point. If that's the point, database storage makes the most sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know the following is not an optimal way to do this, but it works and is guaranteed to return `the same` random number between 1 and 9, which will be unique for each user, i.e. you wont need to store it in your database:

```
require 'digest/md5'

def unique_number_for(user)
  hash = (Digest::MD5.new << user.id.to_s).to_s
  hash.split("").map(&:to_i).detect {|a| a > 0}
end
```

Comment: This code breaks if all the digits are a-f, but the odds of that are (I think) 1 in 2.3E-14.  I'm not going to wait around for it to happen.

Answer (score -3):

The obvious solution:

`id.to_s[-1,1]`

Comment: Yeah, assuming your IDs are continuous, ascending integers.

Comment: Well, if he's using the primary key id created by Rails, he should be fine for ascending integers, right?

Comment: Firstly, it should be: `id.to_s[-1,1].to_i`. Secondly, this solution will include `0` in its results, which the OP states is unwanted.

Comment: What the f***! :P and, I came up with a solution for his use case.. :P removed the downvote.. ;)

Comment: That's not "random", that's completely predictable. That doesn't answer the question you asked, which is about random numbers between **one** and nine.